# Django cache doesn't store all cached elements

Tags: django, caching

I'm used DB and filebased cache with my django 1.4.1 project.
I have more than 100 000 elements that should be cached, they are caching for 48 hours. 
But elements in cache are disapearing too early and cache coverage is about 10%.

For example, main page should be generated only one time in 48 hours, but It get's from cache only 30% of hits, other 70% of requests doesn't find cached version and regenerates main page.

```
cache_time = 60*60*24*2
body_html = cache.get('index')
if not body_html:
    body_html = generate_page_html_content()
    cache.set('index', body_html, cache_time)
#do something with body_html
```

For db cache `SELECT count(*) FROM cache;` returned 224 cached items but there should be much more of them. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#cache-arguments

I added `MAX_ENTRIES` option and set limit, that is suitable for me.